# Get the total of item in "char *namelist[]" in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array of names stored in `char *namelist[]`.  When I pass it to a function, I'm unable to display all of the names in the `namelist`:

```
int ReadListOfName(const char* names[])
{
  //Note: I always get the len = 1
  //      Anyway I can get total items in names

  int len = sizeof(names)/sizeof(char*);
  for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    printf("%d-%s\n",i,names[i]);

  return 0;

}

int main(void)
{
  const char* names[] = {"a","b","c"};
  ReadListOfName(names);
  return 0;
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> int len = sizeof(names)/sizeof(char*);
> ```

This doesn't get you the number of elements, `sizeof` doesn't do what you want on pointers. You have to pass the length as an additional argument to the function. Also discussed in this [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmsize.html). You could try:

```
int ReadListOfName(const char* names[], size_t len)
/* ... */

ReadListOfName(names, sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int ReadListOfName(const char* names[])
```

In this `names` essentially becomes `char **` rather than `char * []` as defined your `main`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass in another argument to `ReadListOfName` specifying the length of the array or have a terminating value in your array like `argv` does. When passed to a function, an array will *decay* to a pointer; a `char*[]` will decay to a `char**`, as you're passing the address of the first element in the array. Therefore your function is in fact interpreted as:

```
int ReadListOfName(const char **names)
```

And you're actually equating `sizeof(char**)/sizeof(char*)`, which won't give you the number of elements in the array (it'll probably give you 1).

Add a length argument and then just calculate `len` before passing it `ReadListOfName`.

Note that rather than dividing `sizeof(names)` by `sizeof(char*)` to get the number of elements in the array, you can instead divide by `sizeof(*names)`, and you wouldn't need to worry about changing `char*` if you change the type of the elements in `names`:

```
int len = sizeof(names)/sizeof(*names);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers already explain what happens to the array reference when passing it to the function, please find an approach to solve the issue without adding another parameter to the method printing the names.

You might like to add a stopper element to your list like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ReadListOfName(const char ** names)
{
  for (int i=0; names[i]; i++)
    printf("%d-%s\n",i,names[i]);

  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  const char* names[] = {"a","b","c", NULL}; /* Please note the additional, last element. */
  ReadListOfName(names);
  return 0;
}
```

The essential difference of this approach to the one passing two arguments discribing the list `names[]`, is the fact that **its use is less error-prone** as the information of the list's size is **drawn from the list itself**, but from a second **independently** provided value.

Answer (score 0):

**sizeof(AnyPointer)** gives word size. In case of 32-bit OS, 4 will be returned. similarly 8 will be returned in 64-bit machine.

So `sizeof(char*) == sizeof(float*) == sizeof(int*)` is true.

```
If your OS is 32-bit,
sizeof(names) will be 4.
sizeof(char*) also 4.
```

Obviously you will get `len = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass an additional argument which will explicitly mention the length of the array. and where you are initializing setup some MACRO to fiddle with sizeofs.